# Arithmetic Order of Operation

Tags: arithmetic

What is the square root of -4 + 13 x 8 - (7 + 2(3 + 20/5))

The answer seems to be 3 but I wanted help trying to get to the answer!

Comment: $3 + 20/5 = 7$, so $(7 + 2(3 + 20/5)) = 7 + 2\cdot 7 = 21$. We then have $-4 + 13 \cdot 8 - 21 = 79$, and it gives $\sqrt{79}$.

Comment: welcome to mathematic forum,but for such simplest  arithmetic terms,please pay more attention before ask it

Comment: @Raphaela i have answered and please see it

Comment: and last note for the future  ,please whenever your problem is solved,show it others by accepting this answer,which helped you,because  it will encourage others to help you and also your reputation would be increased.good lucks

Answer (score 1):

using BODMAS :

$$-4+13*8-(7+2(3+20/5))$$
$$-4+13*8-(7+2*7)$$
$$-4+13*8-(7+14)$$
$$-4+13*8-21$$
$$-4+104-21$$
$$79$$
now squre root $79$

Answer (score 0):

ok let us calculate seperately

first in brackets

```
1.20/5=4

2.3+4=7

3.2*7=14

4.7+14=21

5.13*8=104

6.104-21=83

7.83-4=79
```

$\sqrt{79}=8.888194417315589$